# Can our individual site flair show that site's badges?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, flair

This is a kinda small thing, but right now the User Flair just uses generic flair icons, like the trilogy uses. This is fine for those sites; however, I really like my coin badges. Can we have it use the site's actual badge pictures?

i.e. This is how it looks now:

[image: profile for Ullallulloo at Gaming, Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms]

I'd rather it look something like this:

[image: profile for Ullallulloo at Gaming, Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms]

Only, with proper spacing of course. :p

Comment: An excellent suggestion.  Technical difficulty, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you'd rather it show a gold badge. ;)

Comment: @gnostradamus: Got one now! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require se.com to retrieve and dynamically render -- through C# code -- the CSS of the site as it is displayed in the browser.

Technically infeasible.

Comment: Aw, I figured that you could do it same way as the site's icon... :(

Comment: @ulla but the site's icon is available standalone as favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png -- no such luck for the badge sprites